# Ubuntu 14.04 Startup application command for Indicator Application

Tags: startup-applications

Can someone post the command for the Indicator Application in Startup Applications? I deleted it by accident and I wanted to add it back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is indicator application command (for 64 bit ubuntu):
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-application/indicator-application-service